# How do I pipe each line from a cmd output to a column in a table created from Microsoft SQL?

Tags: cmd, pycharm, sql-server-2014, python-3.6, wmic

I have tried this particular command and I know that it works.

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %i in (`wmic/node:'+adr+' product get installdate ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do @echo %i
```

The "adr" would be replaced with an IP address, and the concatenation and extra apostrophes would be removed. When I use it in Python, I do use the subprocess.call() method, and it works in the console as well.

However, here's the problem I have with this. The main command itself (the wmic/node thing) would print everything out on different lines. This is expected behavior, but I want to do this so that each install date writes to the next row in the same column of a table created in a database on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, rather than just one line. I have tried to look online for a case closely similar to this one, but I've had no such luck.

Here is what my code looks like, I'm not sure if I should change anything to get the desired result.

```
installdate = subprocess.call('for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %i in (`wmic/node:'+adr+' product get installdate ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do @echo %i', shell=True)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO InstalledApps (InstallDate) VALUES (?)", installdate)
```

Comment: Please review the subprocess.call documentation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html It returns the exit code, not the output of the command. See `stdout=` to capture the output.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I see that you are on Python 3.6. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html The subprocess.run() function is now recommended.